# Store and Change dinamically TCP Port in SQL Connection String

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I handle Sql 2014 Express and this eventually changes the TCP Dynamic Port. Since the applications of vb.net need to have a connectionString, it would be laborious to be adjusting the already compiled exe programs, each time the TCP port included in the conectionstring of my applications changes in the company network. How can I store a connectionstring in the local network in a single point so I can modify it when I change the tcp port to eventually restart the sql server? In such a way that the vbnet applications access by network to a single point where the connectionstring is stored? What is the best technique in these cases?

Comment: Configure it to use fixed port

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/tcp-ip-properties-ip-addresses-tab?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are running the SQL Server Browser service, you won't need to know the port number, just the instance name.

Comment: The problem is: Some pc don't detect de Instance by name: SERVER\INSTANCE, then in that cases we need to use instead: SERVER, PORT.   So, the problem is that in some cases the only way to connect from certain PCs is to use the specific TCP port, and that is where the inconvenience of the changing port arises.

Comment: you can use fixed port if that is the case but i would double check that the browser service is running, directing to the correct port is its main purpose